# wrong expression result linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I want to get records with parentIds. But this Linq expression gave me elements with 0 parentId value.

```
var orders =
    OrderEquityTransactions.AsParallel().Where(
        o => o.FinancialInstrumentId == financialInstrumentPrice.FinancialInstrumentId &&
            o.ParentId != 0 &&
        o.DebitCredit == "A" ? o.Price >= financialInstrumentPrice.Price : o.Price <= financialInstrumentPrice.Price).ToList();
```

After some digging I rewrote expression with additional two brackets and problem solved.

```
var orders =
    OrderEquityTransactions.AsParallel().Where(
        o => o.FinancialInstrumentId == financialInstrumentPrice.FinancialInstrumentId &&
            o.ParentId != 0 &&
        (o.DebitCredit == "A" ? o.Price >= financialInstrumentPrice.Price : o.Price <= financialInstrumentPrice.Price)).ToList();
```

What is the reason of this behavior?

Comment: Operator precedence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in the first case it was interpreted as:

```
o => (o.FinancialInstrumentId == financialInstrumentPrice.FinancialInstrumentId 
   && o.ParentId != 0 && o.DebitCredit == "A") 
  ? o.Price >= financialInstrumentPrice.Price 
  : o.Price <= financialInstrumentPrice.Price
```

which is absolutely another.

Please, read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx) on operator precedence.
Ternary conditional operator has the lower priority than conditional AND.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Operator precedence and associativity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323.aspx), conditional ANDs have a higher precedence than the conditional operator. So C# evaluates your expresion like this:

```
(o.FinancialInstrumentId == financialInstrumentPrice.FinancialInstrumentId 
        && o.ParentId != 0 && o.DebitCredit == "A")
    ? o.Price >= financialInstrumentPrice.Price
    : o.Price <= financialInstrumentPrice.Price
```